# Handling iPhone X notch with autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, iphone-x

I have an imageview, it sits central at the top of the view.

This looks fine on all devices, apart from the iPhone X where the notch crops the image.

Is there a method to position a view from the notch rather than the top horns of the screen? as its causing issue with my layout consistencies

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When laying out the `imageView`, use [safe area guides](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area):

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    // rest of the constraints
])
```

Comment: out of interest, how do i add an offset to this to bring something in from the safe area? i have only used snapkit for layout really